# Jensen's inequality proof for X that takes on only finitely many values.

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis, jensen-inequality

Given $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is convex, then for any $x_1,\dots ,x_n$ and $\lambda_1,\dots ,\lambda_n$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i = 1$,$$
f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i x_i\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i f (x_i) .
$$
Use this equation to prove E[f(X)] $\geqslant$ f(E[X]) for any random variable X that takes on only finitely many values.

My thought is that it's similar to Jensen's inequality, but I don't see how it specifically works for this given condition.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The case $n=2$ reduces to the definition of convexity.  The case $n=3$ follows from the $n=2$ case because ... well, you can write a weighted average of 3 things as a weighted  average of one of them and of a weighted average of the other 2.

Comment: @kimichi lover, Thanks for the reply, I think I know what you mean, but is it possible to write into a formal answer? I'm not sure about what to do for the last step of induction if I follow your idea.

Comment: Suppose $a+b+c=1$.  Write $b=(1-a)(b/(b+c))$ and $c=(1-a)(c/(b+c))$.

Comment: If $X$ is has finite range, the expectation can be reduced to a finite sum. That is $E X = \sum_k p_k X_k$ and $E [f(X)] = \sum_k p_k f(X_k)$.

Comment: Two comments: 1. The first condition condition *is* a form of Jensen's inequality. 2. Not sure what you are asking since, as @copper.hat points out, write the expectation as a sum of a finite number of terms and the condition given to you gives the result right away.  In fact, the final result is also called Jensen's inequality (probability theory form).